# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable when reloading a Gensim model

Tags: python, nlp, save, gensim

I am training a Phrases model to identify bigrams on large corpus using Gensim. When I reload the model I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

My code to save the model (and also the training) is like this one:

```
from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases, Phraser
def train_bigram(corpus):
    sentence_stream = [doc.split(" ") for doc in corpus]
    bigram_model = Phrases(sentence_stream, min_count=180, threshold=3.5)
    return bigram_model

print("train bigram on cleaned text")
phrases = train_bigram(corpus_cleaned)
print("Build faster model for Gensim")
bigram = Phraser(phrases)  # construct faster model (this is only an wrapper)
# Store the bigram model
bigram.save(path_to_save + "bigram"
```

When I have to reload the model what cain I do? At the moment I am using the following:

`bigram_reloaded = Phraser.load(path_to_save + 'bigram')`

but in this case I get the error shown before. Any idea or tips on how to solve?

Comment: Please show the full error stack in your question, so that it's clear which line(s) of code are implicated.

Comment: Solved upgrading the version. I saved a model trained on a remote pc, where there is last Gensim version, and I loaded the model on my laptop where Gensim was not upgraded. Using the same version everything is fine